# Why do I get the error "Camera not Multi-View Camera"?

Tags: rendering, camera, stereoscopy

Stereo3D modes will render fine, but when switching to Multi-View I always get the error, **"Camera 'Camera' in not mutli-view camera"**. The Camera is set to Panoramic with both a left and right camera. I even added a few extras to see if that would change anything.

I've come across this error on the 2.74 branch, the 2.75 Test Build, and 2.75 Release Candidate, so I surely doing something wrong. I've checked the camera settings, render settings, and of course scene settings, not finding a single option anywhere to change the camera type. Even from the [Multi-View document page](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview.html), and the [branch documentation](https://code.blender.org/2015/03/1451/), it is said, "that it should just work".

Does anyone have any idea on how to get the camera to register as a "multi-view" camera?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the "Stereo 3D" mode; there only needs to be one camera present in the scene. The left and right cameras are created as children of the active camera, and their settings are controlled from the "Properties Window" -> "Object Data" tab; in the "Stereoscopy" panel.

Using "Multi-View" each camera needs to be added and positioned manually, however there can be more than two. The "Properties Window" -> "Object Data" tab "Stereoscopy" panel is not added in this mode.

The "Properties Window" -> "Render Layers" tab, "Views" panel contains a list of camera "render views", with left and right already preset.
For each of these render views there is an associated "Suffix" text field.
In "Stereo 3D" mode this suffix field simply appends this text to the filename of the render of each camera.
In "Multi-View" mode this suffix field not only appends the text as above, it also identifies each camera producing a render view, therefore each camera needs to be renamed and should end with the matching suffix (case sensitive).

The error; Camera "Camera_XXX" is not a multi-view camera, seems to occur when the name of the active camera does not end with one of the suffixes defined in the "render views" list, or if the any of the "render views" list suffixes are not assigned to a camera.
(This error message seems to return the name of the active camera, and not necessarily the name of a camera that is not assigned to a "render view".)

Comment: Very cool. That's confusing since Stereo3D doesn't require that, even though it does use two cameras as well. At the same time, it answers my question as to what the suffix was for. 

Anyways, I added another camera, added the suffix to each camera, and all is good. Thanks!

When I was adding cameras above, I was adding them to the list of cameras to use.

Comment: A small hint - the same error occurs if the part before the prefix has been customized. The name has to be "Camera_SUFFIX" and cannot be "my camera name_SUFFIX"

Comment: Thanks! I made a new scene, Output Properties> Stereoscopy> Multi-View. Left everything else default. Renamed my main "Camera" to "Camera_L". Duplicated the camera and renamed the duplicate to "Camera_R". Now I see the red / blue based on those custom cameras. Very cool! Thank you.